# EnumValidator - Could not commit JPA transcation - Not accepting NULL values - Custom Annotation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-annotations

In order to avoid the use of an if statement when I want to check if a given String is an ENUM constant, I implemented EnumValidator:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = EnumHelper.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@NotNull
public @interface EnumValidator {

    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass();

    String message() default "Is not in enum";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

And EnumHelpe which implements ConstraintValidator<EnumValidator, String>:

```
    @Override
    public void initialize(EnumValidator constraintAnnotation) {
        values = Stream.of(constraintAnnotation.enumClass().getEnumConstants())
                .map(Enum::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        values.addAll(Stream.of(constraintAnnotation.enumClass().getEnumConstants())
                .map(Enum::name)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value == null || values.contains(value);

    }
```

Then I added the Annotation to the Entity:

```
  private String degree;
```

And it basically works unless I do not provide this attribute, which means null is not a valid value, even though I set it in isValid() method.

Also, the Message from ExceptionHandler is very poor and only saying "Could not commit JPA transaction". This also occurs when a value is given that is not valid, so the Validation has no conclusive Error message.

Seems like going back to if statements with a simple isInEnum(String string) method works much better even though it takes some more lines of code.

I have checked out many solutions. One was to remove the attribute from the entity, inherit entity to sub class and create the attribute there where NULL value was not a valid option. Like this, I also had proper error messages.

But that solution is not good.

It should be working because "isValid()" returns true when I do not set the field.

I actually came to a better solution. It is very easy compared to my other approaches:

```
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private DegreeEnum degree;
```

Only disadvantage: I cannot use the Enum extension attribute anymore, so I can only check for the Uppercase Enum Constants (which is the .name() method) and not for customized String values and Override toString() method.

I would be happy to make my Custom Validator work as it should. Any ideas?